# Drag events fired on click of pushpin on bingmap

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, pushpin

I attached multiple events (click, dragstart, dragend) events on pushpin but the problem is, when I click pushpin on bing map it calls both drag event first.
I want to restirct drag events when click on pushpin and it should be fired when we drag pushpin on map.

I tried attach multiple event handler on same pin but it's not working.

**Sample code:**

```
    <html>
      <head>
          <script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"   src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
     <script>
        var pinInfoBox;  //the pop up info box
        var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        var pinLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        var apiKey = "Key";

        function GetMap() {

            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { credentials: apiKey });

            // Create the info box for the pushpin
            pinInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { visible: false });
            infoboxLayer.push(pinInfobox);


            for (var i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
                //add pushpins
                var latLon = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(Math.random() * 180 - 90, Math.random() * 360 - 180);
                var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(latLon, { draggable: true });
                pin.Title = name;//usually title of the infobox
                pin.Description = "blahblahblah, " + i; //information you want to display in the infobox
                pinLayer.push(pin); //add pushpin to pinLayer
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', displayInfobox);
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'dragstart', startDragDetails);
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'dragend', endDragDetails);
            }

            map.entities.push(pinLayer);
            map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);

        }

        startDragDetails = function (e) {
            console.log("Start Latitude/Longitude: " + e.entity.getLocation());
        };
        endDragDetails = function (e) {
            console.log("End Latitude/Longitude: " + e.entity.getLocation());
        };

        function displayInfobox(e) {
            console.log("click");
            pinInfobox.setOptions({ title: e.target.Title, description: e.target.Description, visible: true, offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 25) });
            pinInfobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
        }

        function hideInfobox(e) {
            pinInfobox.setOptions({ visible: false });
        }
    </script>

    <style>
        #map {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 10px;
            width: 700px;
            height: 500px;
            border: #555555 2px solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap()">
    <div id="map">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stored the flag value "true" in global variable when it comes to drag method and checking the same flag value on end drag method to execute the code that is needed when pins are dragged.

So if we click pins, it calls the dragging methods but won't execute code that we don't need on click event.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested using Both IE and Chrome and both work as expected when I use the mouse or touch to drag a pushpin. When I drag the start drag event fires, when I stop dragging the drag end event fires, finally the click event fires. The drag end event will always fire before the click or mouseup event. If you want to handle the situation where the user doesn't actually move the pin what you can do if capture the pixel coordinates of the pushpin when the drag start event fires, then compare them to the drag end event pixel coordinates of the pushpin. If they are not the same then the pushpin was dragged and you can do what you wanted when a pushpin is dragged, otherwise ignore the event and wait for the click event. If you want you can also do a quick calculation to find out how far the pushpin was moved in pixel distance and if it is small you may also want to ignore the drag event.

Answer (score 0):

I've only just noticed this in Chrome, so now on dragstart I capture the pin location and then compare this to the pin location at dragend. I needed to round the values though.